# highcharts zero values results in graph half way instead at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I have an issue where when returning 0 values from database, the bars in the graph end up being displayed half way instead of at the bottom starting from 0.

I tried adding min: 0 to yAxis as suggested by the documents. This did nothing. After testing alot I found that only when max is added does this work.The issue is then if the data values returned are greater than the max value at any point, the bar goes shooting outside the graph.

Can someone advise how the bars in this example 
http://jsfiddle.net/2fuRA/71/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            margin: 75,
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 15,
                beta: 15,
                depth: 50
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                depth: 25
            }
        },
        yAxis:{
            min: 0,
        },
        series: [{
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        }]
    });
});
```

are to be set against the floor of the graph instead half way through, without breaking the graph normal function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `minRange` instead of `max`, as this will give the y-axis a small span when all values are `0`, but adjust accordingly when larger values appear.

For example:

```
yAxis:{
    min: 0,
    minRange: 2
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/2fuRA/73/) of how it adapts to updated points with larger values.

Answer (score 0):

It's only like that because all your data is 0. Changing any of those values fixes your graph

Comment: Hi thanks for explanation but my question was how to get it to the floor when all the data is 0